# Not being able to highlight text in Adobe Reader

Tags: adobe-reader

I downloaded a book in pdf format from b-ok.org and opened it in Adobe Reader. I am being able to select text, but not highlight it. So how do I highlight it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### So how do I highlight it?

> **Highlight, strikethrough, or underline text**
>
> Choose Tools > Comment to view the menu bar.
>
> [image]
>
> Choose Tools > Comment to see the menu bar for Highlight Text tool,
>   Strikethrough Text tool, and Underline Text tool
>
> You can use the Highlight Text tool, Strikethrough Text tool, and the
>   Underline Text tool to add comments by themselves or in conjunction
>   with notes.
>
> You can add a highlight with a note or you can cross out text or
>   underline text by selecting the text using the Select tool,
>   right-clicking, and then choosing that option from the menu that
>   appears. However, if you’re marking up a lot of text, the specialized
>   tools are faster and easier to use.
>
> 1. Choose Tools > Comment, and select the Highlight Text tool , the Strikethrough Text tool , or the Underline Text tool .
>
>    Note:
>
>    If you want to apply more than one comment using the Strikeout Text
>      tool or the Underline Text tool, choose Keep Tool Selected from the
>      Options menu after you select the tool. The Highlight Text tool stays
>      selected after you make the first comment.
> 2. Drag from the beginning of the text you want to mark up. Control-drag to mark up a rectangular area of text. This feature is
>      especially useful when you are marking up text in a column.
> 3. (Optional) To add a note, double-click the markup and add text in a pop-up note.
>
> Note that you can also change the color of the highlighted text. Right-click (Windows) or Control-click (Mac OS) on the highlighted text and click Properties to open the Highlight Properties dialog box, which will allow you to change the color.
>
> [image]
>   Source [Mark up text with edits, Adobe Acrobat](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/mark-text-edits.html)

Comment: The highlight tool is disabled for this particular pdf. How do I enable it?